# jQuery time to php

Tags: php, jquery, date, time

I have a this value 112639618, which is the timeleft for a countdown with jQuery, how can I pass that value to something like 06/27/2011 12:33 PM using PHP

Thanks in advance

*** Update ***

jQuery used to output the timeleft

index_bundle.js

```
    var timerCurrentParticipants;var timerTimeLeft;var currentTimeLeft;var secondsForTimer;var secondsForCurrentParticipants;var url_prefix_var;var noEmailText;var subscribeSuccessText;var generalErrorText;var wrongEmailPatternText;var soldText;var participantsText;var dealTakePlaceText;var dealTookPlaceText;var requiredText;var buyerText;var sold2Text;var successfulText;var soldOutText;var requiredOneText;var NewsletterDotd={lastPropertyGroup:"",subscribe:function(url_prefix,value){var url=url_prefix+"/Newsletter.action?subscribeNewsletter=";var v=$('#emailaddress2').val();if(v==''){sendErrorMessage(noEmailText);return false;}
if(/\w{1,}[@][\w\-]{1,}([.]([\w\-]{1,})){1,3}$/.test(v)){$.ajax({type:"POST",url:url,data:({email:$('#emailaddress2').val()}),dataType:"json",success:function(data){if(!data.success){sendErrorMessage(data.message);}else{window.location.href=window.location.href+"?newsletter=subscribe";}},error:function(){sendErrorMessage(generalErrorText);}});}else{sendErrorMessage(wrongEmailPatternText);}}};var Index={start:function(url_prefix,noEmail,subscribeSuccess,generalError,wrongEmailPattern,sold,participants,dealTakePlace,dealTookPlace,required,buyer,sold2,successful,soldOut,requiredOne){noEmailText=noEmail;subscribeSuccessText=subscribeSuccess;generalErrorText=generalError;wrongEmailPatternText=wrongEmailPattern;soldText=sold;participantsText=participants;dealTakePlaceText=dealTakePlace;dealTookPlaceText=dealTookPlace;requiredText=required;buyerText=buyer;sold2Text=sold2;successfulText=successful;soldOutText=soldOut;requiredOneText=requiredOne;url_prefix_var=url_prefix;currentTimeLeft=$('#currentTimeLeft').val();secondsForTimer=1000;secondsForCurrentParticipants=300000;Index.setInitialTimer();timerCurrentParticipants=setInterval(function(){Index.getCurrentParticipants(url_prefix,false);},secondsForCurrentParticipants);timerTimeLeft=setInterval(function(){Index.setTimer();},secondsForTimer);},getCurrentParticipants:function(url_prefix,finished){var url=url_prefix+"/DealOfTheDay.action?getCurrentParticipants=";$.ajax({url:url,data:({dotdId:$('#dotdId').val(),alreadyFinished:finished}),dataType:"json",success:function(data){if(!data.success){}else{var replacedText=sold2Text.replace(/\{0\}/,data.currentParticipants);$('#contentDealStatusBox .soldAmount').empty().append(replacedText);if(Number(data.currentParticipants)>0){$('#contentDealStatusBox .soldAmount').show();}
var currentPercent=Number(data.currentParticipantsPercent);var displayPercent=Math.round(currentPercent*1.84);$('.progressBarMarker').css('width',(displayPercent+16)+'px');$('.progressBarSliderMid').css('width',(displayPercent)+'px');if(data.minReached){if($('#contentDealStatusBox .progressBarNumbers').html()!='<br/>'){$('#contentDealStatusBox .progressBarNumbers').html('<br/>');$('.progressBar').delay(800).hide('slow');$('#dealTakePlace').show();}}else{if(data.participantsLeft==1){$('#contentDealStatusBox .progressBarNumbersText').html(requiredOneText);}
else{$('#req_part').text(data.participantsLeft);}}
if(data.finished){$('#dealTakePlace').hide();if(data.minReached){$('#contentDealStatusBox .dealRunning').empty().append("<span>"+successfulText+"</span>");}else{$('#contentDealStatusBox .dealRunning').empty().append("<span>"+soldOutText+"</span>");}
clearInterval(timerCurrentParticipants);$('#contentDealStatusBox .dealRunning').hide();$('#contentDealStatusBox .dealSuccessful #dealTookPlace').show();}}},error:function(){}});},setTimer:function(){currentTimeLeft=parseInt(currentTimeLeft-secondsForTimer);if(currentTimeLeft<=0){$('#hoursLeft').empty().append("00");$('#minutesLeft').empty().append("00");$('#secondsLeft').empty().append("00");$('#timerBlock').hide();Index.getCurrentParticipants(url_prefix_var,true);clearInterval(timerTimeLeft);}else{var wholeSeconds=parseInt(currentTimeLeft/1000);var wholeMinutes=parseInt(currentTimeLeft/60000);var wholeHours=parseInt(wholeMinutes/60);var seconds=parseInt(wholeSeconds%60);var minutes=parseInt(wholeMinutes%60);var days=parseInt(wholeHours/24);var hours=parseInt(wholeHours%24);if(wholeHours<10){$('#hoursLeft').empty().append("0"+wholeHours);}else{$('#hoursLeft').empty().append(wholeHours);}
if(minutes<10){$('#minutesLeft').empty().append("0"+minutes);}else{$('#minutesLeft').empty().append(minutes);}
if(seconds<10){$('#secondsLeft').empty().append("0"+seconds);}else{$('#secondsLeft').empty().append(seconds);}}},setInitialTimer:function(){if(currentTimeLeft<=0){$('#timerBlock').hide();Index.getCurrentParticipants(url_prefix_var,true);clearInterval(timerTimeLeft);}else{var wholeSeconds=parseInt(currentTimeLeft/1000);var wholeMinutes=parseInt(currentTimeLeft/60000);var wholeHours=parseInt(wholeMinutes/60);var seconds=parseInt(wholeSeconds%60);var minutes=parseInt(wholeMinutes%60);var days=parseInt(wholeHours/24);var hours=parseInt(wholeHours%24);if(wholeHours<10){$('#hoursLeft').empty().append("0"+wholeHours);}else{$('#hoursLeft').empty().append(wholeHours);}
if(minutes<10){$('#minutesLeft').empty().append("0"+minutes);}else{$('#minutesLeft').empty().append(minutes);}
if(seconds<10){$('#secondsLeft').empty().append("0"+seconds);}else{$('#secondsLeft').empty().append(seconds);}}}};function toggleAcceptNewsletterOptin(){var checked=$('#jAcceptNewsletterOptin').val();$('#jAcceptNewsletterOptin').val((checked=="true"?"false":"true"));}
```

On the page I get a input like this: `<input type="hidden" id="currentTimeLeft" value="153601525"/>`

Comment: You have to provide much more information. What is the overall scenario? How do you want to "pass" that value?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you need help 1) transferring the data (probably via AJAX) to PHP (and perhaps back to the web browser?) or 2) formatting time in PHP specifically or 3) formatting the time in general (which you can do without needing PHP) or 4) some combination of the above? If 1–3, edit your question to make clear which. If 4, make a new question for each part you need, and edit this question to reflect one part of it.

Comment: `time left for a countdown` suggests it's just some number of (milli)seconds. You'd need a base date to add that time value to to get an actual date.

Comment: what a mass of confusion

Comment: Please format your code so that other people are able to **read** it! All I see is a buch of characters. It is impossible to figure at the structure of the code (how can you?).

Comment: Format ? in which way ?, the code is already working in that way

Comment: @daniel: Formatting means to make use of line breaks, spaces and indentation so that it is possible to **read** the code. I'm not talking about the functionality of the code. E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TtMnr/ Do you really think someone understand your code if you put everything in one line? And if you have no problems with the code, why do you post it at all?

Answer (score 0):

A short google would give you the same result. Make use of the [php time function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php). In your case it would be something like this:

```
<?php
echo date('m/d/o/g/i', 112639618);
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code prints 07/27/1973/4/46, a bit outdated

Comment: You have to provide more information. I assumed that the number is a unix-timestamp.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question now whit the jQuery that output the timeleft